# Screen lock/unlock detection in Ionic App

Tags: plugins, ionic-framework

My question, is there a way for a ionic app to detect whether the device screen is locked/unlocked? I do know the app can detect when it becomes 'paused' and is running in the background but this is not what I mean. The reason for this is I want to make a geolocation function that only runs while the device screen is unlocked. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

you can use ionic events `pause` `resume` see this snippet

```
.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
  $ionicPlatform.on("resume", function() {
    // do something update your interval
  }

  $ionicPlatform.on("pause", function() {
    // do something here to store the timestamp
  }

});
```

Comment: Yes I realize I have those events, only problem is pause gets triggered when the device locks. And thats when I need my functionality to stop. I need to specifically detect the lock and unlock. Thanks for you answer